# finding sidebar content in wordpress

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

Hey all i have been trying to find the content that loads up for a page for a few days now and can not seem to find where its located.

This is the WP code that seems to populate the content:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
  register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => 'home-top-sidebar',
    'name' => 'Home Top Sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="visual"><div class="visual-holder">',
    'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
));
```

However, like i stated above, i am unable to find where its pulling that data from?!!? The content doesn't seem to be located in any page on the site nor is it in the database?

The content that i am interested in goes inbetween the **before_widget** and the **after_widget**

The html code when rendered on the page that loads up looks like this (the part where i am trying to find the content from):

```
<div class="visual">
   <div class="visual-holder">
      <img src="http://xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxzteye/images/img1.jpg" alt="image description" width="974" height="408">
      <div class="visual-text">
          <h2>State-of-the-art technologies</h2>
           <p>in the most experienced hands.</p>
      </div>        
   </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone point me to the area where this is being pulled from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The content for a dynamic sidebar is whatever widgets are added to that sidebar from the backend.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar) Look at wp-admin->Appearance->Widgets. The actual code for those widgets could come from WordPress itself, a plugin, or your theme.

But...

> The content that i am interested in goes inbetween the < div
>   class="visual"> and the < div class="visual-holder">

.. nothing goes between those two `<div>`s. They are hard coded to be nested like that. Your content is inside the second one, which is inside the first.

Answer (score 0):

There are three places to look:

1. To find where the output is controlled, look in your **Theme Template Files**, for a call to: **`dynamic_sidebar( 'home-top-sidebar' )`**. Given the name of the sidebar, I would look in `front-page.php`, or `home.php`, or in `sidebar.php`.
2. To find the Widgets assigned to the `home-top-sidebar` sidebar, go to **`Dashboard->Appearance->Widgets`**, and open the **Home Top Sidebar** tab in the list of Widget areas in the right column.
3. To find the Widgets assigned to the `home-top-sidebar` sidebar, you can also look in the database, Look for the `theme_mods_<themename>` options.